# How to fork my own repo into a new project?

Tags: git, github, svc

I was developing an HTML5 game engine. I used Git as the SV  and GitHub to actually host the project.

I've made some substantial changes in the design (mainly switching to the Entity System paradigm), and I think it's time for a new engine.

I would like to base it off the old engine, as there is a lot of code that I can use.

What would be the standard way of doing this? The new engine will have a new name, and the old one will be considered "finished".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want a new project with a new repo, but sharing history with the old one, then the simple way is

```
$ git clone https://github.com/your_name/old_project new_project
# make new, empty project on GitHub called new_project
$ cd new_project
$ git remote rename origin old_project
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/your_name/new_project
$ git push -u origin
```

Now you have a new project, but in your local clone you can still get commits from the old one to get bugfixes to common code with `git cherry-pick` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to branch

```
git branch <your_new_branch>
git checkout <your_new_branch>
```

to switch back to old branch

```
git checkout master
```

to list all branches

```
git branch
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use branches for this. The new engine should be a whole new project, with its own GitHub directory. The old one is finished and I want it listed as such on my GitHub page.

Comment: for that you create a new repo on github an add its git address to remotes in ```git remote add new_repo git://github.com/foo/bar``` now onwards you can push to that repo saying ```git push new_repo your_branch```. I would recommend you doing a hardcore fork of your project if newer version is based on previous one.

Comment: What do you mean by "hardcore fork"?